# Product of Independent Gaussian Variables

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, random-variable

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent normal distributions according to $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,P)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,Q)$. Is it true to say the following ?

1. $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$
2. $\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$
3. $\mathbb{E}[XY^2]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=0$
4. $\mathbb{E}[X^2Y^2]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=PQ$

Comment: **Hint**: What the independence assumption implies on the expectation of the product?

Comment: @Procrastinator Due to the independence of $X$ and $Y$, $p(x,y) = p(x)p(y)$. So, $\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]=\int\int x^2yp(x,y)dxdy=\int x^2p(x)dx\int y^2p(y)dy=\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y]=0$. Is this reasoning correct ?

Comment: Indeed. This reasoning answers $1.$, $2.$, and $3.$. For $4.$ you have to use the definition of variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key result is the following:

> If $U$ and $V$ are two *independent* random variables (not necessarily Gaussian), then $E(UV)=E(U)E(V)$.

It's easy to see this when the random variable have density, because if $g(u,v)$ is a density of $(U,V)$, we can actually write it as $f_1(u)f_2(v)$, where $f_1$ is a density of $U$ and $f_2$ those of $V$. Then we use Fubini's theorem.

Note that independence is preserved under continuous mapping (more generally under measurable ones, but it's not needed). Namely, if $h_1$ and $h_2$ are continuous, and $U$ and $V$ are independent random variables, so are $h_1(U)$ and $h_1(V)$.

This justifies the equalities in the OP.